# Adding Ids wit EFCore does not affect auto increment value PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core

I am using PostgreSQL 15.0 in combination with EFCore. As I want to set up a demo environment with one click, I set `modelBuilder.UseIdentityByDefaultColumns();` in my `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method.

My demo data setup then looks like this:

```cs
context.DropDowns.AddRange(new List<DropDown>()
{
    new()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Value = "Value1",
    },
    new()
    {
        Id = 2,
        Value = "Value2",
    },
});
```

I manually set the ID as I use the IDs to set my FK values in other entities.
But when I then want to add a new value (where PostgreSQL should autogenerate the ID), it reuses an existing PK, and I get the following error message:

> SQL Error [23505]: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_DropDowns"
> Detail: Key ("Id")=(2) already exists.
> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_DropDowns"
> Detail: Key ("Id")=(2) already exists.
> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_DropDowns"
> Detail: Key ("Id")=(2) already exists.

Every time I click on save, the ID it tries to use is incremented by one, so after two times in this example (as I added two `DropDown`s with a fixed ID), it works fine. How could I handle this issue with mixed use of autogenerated Ids and manually set IDs?

Comment: Having manual and auto-generated Ids is generally not very workable, but a couple possibilities. 1. Define your auto-generated as a sequence and specify a [start with](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) of 10000, or more. 2. Use negative numbers for your manually entered Ids. You could even create decreasing value sequence (increment by -1) and use it strictly for "manually" entered Ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now use negative values as IDs in my demo data:

```cs
context.DropDowns.AddRange(new List<DropDown>()
{
    new()
    {
        Id = -1,
        Value = "Value1",
    },
    new()
    {
        Id = -2,
        Value = "Value2",
    },
});
```